# CorePlot - error - expected expression for typedef NSString *CPTExceptionType cpt_swift_struct

Tags: objective-c, xcode7, core-plot

Parameters:

1. using Xcode 7.3.1
2. writing in Objective-C
3. deploying for iOS 8.3
4. using CorePlot 2.2
5. carefully followed all instructions from "Using Core Plot Within an Application" https://code.google.com/archive/p/core-plot/wikis/UsingCorePlotInApplications.wiki

When I compile my code, I receive the error `expected expression` for the `typedef NSString *CPTExceptionType cpt_swift_struct`.

I don't know if this is a result of me not specifying in Xcode that I may be using the Swift language for certain things (I'm in no way coding in Swift, but some of the classes in CorePlot 2.2 incorporate it).  If that's the case, where do I specify that combination?

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Core Plot 2.2 relies on the Swift 3 features available beginning in Xcode 8. Either upgrade to Xcode 8.x or use Core Plot 2.1.